# Making IF ELSE statement with combinations of choice

Tags: php

Currently I'm making an application to suggest a car that suits the users' preferences based on their selection. I'd skip the HTML form but the choices are as follow:

Type: MPV, SUV, Sedan 
Passengers: 5, 7 
Engine: Gasoline, Diesel 
Budget: Low, Medium, High, Luxury

Here I'm trying to make a combination because I want that every single choice counts. Therefore this is what I've done so far:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])
{
 $type = $_POST['type'];
 $passengers = $_POST['passengers'];
 $engine = $_POST['engine'];
 $budget = $_POST['budget'];

 if ($type == 'MPV' && $passengers == 5 && $engine == 'Gasoline' && $budget == 'Low')
 {
   // execute my function here
 } 
 else if ($type == 'MPV' && $passengers == 7 && $engine == 'Gasoline' && $budget == 'Low')
 {
   // execute my function here
 } 
 else if ($type == 'MPV' && $passengers == 5 && $engine == 'Diesel' && $budget == 'Low')
 {
   // execute my function here
 }  
 // and it goes on and on......
```

I know my problem is I will have to keep making if/elseif function until I list every single possible combination. Now is there any better way to do this? I need to get every single possible combination because there are additional calculations to be done in my custom function.

Here is my custom function:

```
public function calculateDetails($displacement_bottom, $displacement_top, $price_bottom, $price_top, $clearance)
{
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT id, brand, name FROM cars
                                WHERE type = '$type'
                                AND displacement BETWEEN '$displacement_bottom' AND '$displacement_top'
                                AND price BETWEEN '$price_bottom' AND '$price_top'
                                AND clearance = '$clearance'
                                AND passengers = '$passengers'
                                AND engine = '$engine'
                                LIMIT BY 3");
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        $result = echo htmlspecialchars($row['brand'])." ".htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

So I can do this

```
if ($type == 'MPV' && $passengers == 5 && $engine == 'Gasoline' && $budget == 'Low')
{
    $suggestion = calculateDetails(1500, 2000, 100, 150, 'Medium');
    echo $suggestion;
} else if ($type == 'MPV' && $passengers = 7 && $engine == 'Gasoline' && $budget = 'Low')
{
    // continue on and on...
}
```

Since I couldn't find a way to simplify the if/else "loop" (and I started thinking about giving up :( ), I came into few new functions

```
public function typeDetails($type)
{
    if ($type == 'MPV')
    {
        $detailed_type = echo "1500 AND 2000"; 
    }
    else if ($type == 'SUV')
    {
        $detailed_type = echo "2000 AND 3500";
    }
    else
    {
        $detailed_type = echo "2000 AND 3000";
    }
    return $detailed_type;
}

public function budgetDetails($budget)
{
    if ($budget == 'Low')
    {
        $detailed_price = echo "100 AND 150";
    }
    else if ($type == 'Medium')
    {
        $detailed_price = echo "150 AND 250";
    }
    else if ($type == 'High')
    {
        $detailed_price = echo "250 AND 450";
    }
    else
    {
        $detailed_price = echo "450 AND 800";
    }
    return $detailed_price;
}

public function groundClearance($type)
{
    if ($type == 'MPV')
    {
        $ground_clearance = "Medium"; 
    }
    else if ($type == 'SUV')
    {
        $ground_clearance = "High";
    }
    else
    {
        $ground_clearance = "Low";
    }
    return $ground_clearance;
}
```

In which I hope to be able to do this instead

```
$type = $_POST['type'];
$budget = $_POST['budget'];

$displacement = typeDetails($type);
$price = budgetDetails($budget);

// same function but with simplified where clause
$suggestion = calculateDetails($displacement, $price, $clearance);
echo $suggestion;
```

I'm too tired to continue today, but thanks to you guys I came up into few more ideas. I appreciate all the replies and comments given here. I might not be that good in PHP, therefore I want to learn how to make things simpler

Comment: Can you tell what is your function that will be executed for conditions ?

Comment: What is the difference for each function that you execute - knowing what the additional calculations are would help us help you.

Comment: Do you want to make a matrix by hand that covers all possible input combinations and maps to a predetermined outcome? Or do you want to write a system which comes up with something that best fits the input? If the latter, you want something like a point system. Each car you have has certain characteristics (number of passengers etc.), and an algorithm checks which model fulfils all the requested criteria, or at least comes closest…

Comment: My custom function is actually a mysql select query but with lots of parameters. Because in cars, other than those 4, there are other elements that should be considered. But those are basically just a simple SELECT...WHERE clause, that's why I don't include them in my question

Comment: I don't how to call it but I think matrix is the closest to my imagination. However I'm not that good in mapping a matrix. That's why I can only mention each and every if/else function until all possible combinations are fulfilled

Comment: Seeing some of your expected output - ie the final query - may enable us to give you more help. At the moment we can only give very generic solutions - we may be able to give much better solutions if you can show us exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There, I updated my codes. No, it's okay. I appreciate any answers given. I know this is a problem I should have never created before lol, but I'm interested to make this possible. Because I want to apply this concept somewhere else

Answer (score 4):

There is not much you can do here. As an alternative option, you may create kind of a matrix for your models using multi level array:

```
$matrix = [
    'MPV' => [
        'Diesel' => [
            5 => [
                'Low' => function() { ... },
                'Medium' => function() { ... },
            ],
        ],
        'Gasoline' => [ ... ],
    ],
    'SUV' => [ ... ],
];

if (isset($matrix[$type][$engine][$passengers][$budget])) {
    $matrix[$type][$engine][$passengers][$budget]();
}
```

You may also reuse some functions if they don't differ too much or set special constants instead of functions to be passed to a single custom method. It really depends on the *actual* functionality you have for each combination.

Comment: It may be that the calculations performed are the same for each option (e.g. 7 seats adds £xxx for all cases, medium budget always adds 10% to cost) - so there may simplifications that can be made if we know what _"additional calculations to be done in my custom function."_

Comment: @PaulF Yeah, that's why I mentioned in the answer that all that functions may be replaced with some constants that could be passed to one single method to do the calculations. And we can't say more now.

Answer (score 0):

Well I will pick that your function will be to choose a car, so you can add all options that you have (ex 3 different cars) into your database and have 4 values for each :

1. Type
2. Passengers
3. Engine
4. Budget

And set default value for each car :

ex for this condition :

```
$type == 'MPV' && $passengers == 5 && $engine == 'Gasoline' && $budget == 'Low'
```

1. Type = 1
2. Passengers = 1
3. Engine = 1
4. Budget = 1

And regarding clients choosing different options, you can filter your query and select the car that match the search !

Ex :

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM car WHERE type = :type AND passengers = :passengers AND engine = :engine AND budget = :budget");
```

Comment: This is what I initially done. But the problem is my users don't really understand the technical terminologies in my current application. So I want to make my application more friendly for the user, with the cost of being more complex on the inside. For example: I'm planning to discard "MPV" as a choice in the form. Rather I'd put "Family Car" where it includes MPV, 7 passengers and low to medium budget. That's why I need to get all the combinations.

Comment: Well, you can still use this method ! you just need to get information you need and your users don't need to know what happened ! You can set value for a family car as : 1.1.1.1 and it will search for all rows which match !